# How to force parent class to keep value of its protected property?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` that `Bar` extends `Foo` as below:

```
class Foo {
    protected 
        $options = array(), 
        $defaults = array(1, 2);

    public function __construct($options){
        array_push($this->options, $this->defaults);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected $defaults = array(3, 4);

    public function print(){
        print_r($this->$options);
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->print();
```

i thought that result should be `array(1,2,3,4)` but is `array(3,4)`.
how to solve that ?

**edit**
i don't want Bar class to have constructor because i'm just implementer of superclass and don't know what really will happen in child class.

Comment: You are just pushing elements to `$options` in `Foo`'s constructor but you are instanciating `Bar`. That wont call `Foo`'s constructor. So what you get is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions, the simplest would be a second variable to be used as an extended defaults, then merge the arrays.

```
class Foo {
    protected
        $options = array(),
        $original_defaults = array(1, 2),
        $extended_defaults = array();

    public function __construct($options){
        array_merge($this->extended_defaults, $this->original_defaults);
        array_push($this->options, $this->original_defaults);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected $extended_defaults = array(3, 4);

    public function print(){
        print_r($this->$options);
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->print();
```

Comment: That could solve the problem, just i don't want `Bar` class to have constructor

Comment: Good, but the problem is that this solution just work for two level inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it combine your arrays?

You set `$defaults` to `(1,2)` and then to `(3,4)` - nowhere are you concatenating them.

Your constructor adds `(1,2)` onto `$options`. That's all it does.

Your print method outputs `$defaults` which at this point would be `(3,4)` because you initialise them as a protected var.

Comment: I know what happens here, just want the parent class to append it's values to it's child class `$options`. do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Add a constructor to Bar containing the same code as Foo's `__constructor` - Foo's constructor will add `(1,2)` to `$options` - then Bar's constructor would add `(3,4)` (possibly. I can't vouch for that - I can't _exactly_ remember where in object construction the initialisation of member variables happens - personally I would initialise $defaults in each constructor just so you have more clarity of when things occur.) Just out of interest, why do you need this behaviour - it seems a complicated way of just adding elements to an array?

Comment: as i mentioned in update, i don't want `Bar` class to have constructor

Comment: Why don't you want a constructor for an object - that seems like a very odd restriction!

Comment: absolutely is not odd, in a modular program there is no warranty that plugin writer implements constructor or not.

Comment: No, it's not odd that there might not be a constructor. It's odd that you _definitely_ don't want one - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want those values to be overridden then use `private` instead of `protected`. This will prevent subclasses from overriding those values.

Comment: I just want each child class could have it's default values. if i make `$defaults` private, then i can't initial int in child class

Comment: if i make it private `Foo` class only has access to its `$defaults` property

Comment: Oh I see, I've removed my answer, because Truth has already posted one and in such a case I'd do something similar.

Comment: @Omid Amraei: "I just want each child class could have it's default values" Its a good idea, but, you forgot to added to the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First- You cannot have a method named `print`.  `print` is a language construct and cannot be overridden.

Second- you should make the default values for a class private, and override them in child classes.  Then you can combine them in the parent when you call the constructor.  It's not 100% clear what you're trying to accomplish, but the following will merge the sub-class' default options with the superclass':

**Updated to remove constructor**

```
abstract class Foo {
    protected $options = array();

    private $defaults = array(1, 2);

   // Implementations of this class MUST define this method
   abstract function overrideDefaults(); 

    public function __construct($options = array()){
        // Merge any incoming options with the default options
        $this->options = array_merge($this->defaults, $options);

    }

    // Concrete children can use this method to modify the current options by 
    // passing in their own defaults.
    protected function modifyDefaults( $defaults ) {
        $this->options= array_merge( $this->defaults, $defaults );
    }

    public function printOps(){
        print_r($this->options);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    private $defaults = array(3, 4);

    public function overrideDefaults() {
        parent::modifyDefaults( $this->defaults );
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->overrideDefaults();
$bar->printOps();
```

Notice I also moved the now `printOps` method to the superclass.  Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

Comment: But you implemented the constructor in child class, think i'm just writer of super class.

Comment: If you want the child class to be able to pass data to the super class, then the child class either MUST implement a constructor, or you can make the superclass abstract and force concrete implementations to define a method to pass that data.

Comment: abstraction seems to be a good idea, i'm looking for a solution to not force child classes to do anything special like implementing a baffler function.

Comment: @OmidAmraei like I said earlier, if you want the child class to be able to pass information to its parent, there has to be a way for it to do so (_some_ kind of method, whether it be a constructor or not)

Answer (score 0):

"I just want each child class could have it's default values".

You want to have specific data for each class.

You can use "static fields", make class act as a variable, by itself. Im not very fan of "static members", but I think, it applies to your "use case".

```
class Foo {
    private 
      // (1) "private" only accessed by the class itself,
      // neither external code, or subclasses,
      // (2) "static", specific to the class,
      static $defaults = array(1, 2);

    protected 
      // want to be accessed only by class & subclasses
      $options = array();

    // when using "static fields" in constructor,
    // you need to override constructor
    public function __construct($options){
        array_push($this->options, Foo::$defaults);
    }

    // ops, "print" is reserved identifier
    // public function print(){

    public function display_options() {
        print_r($this->$options);
    }

    public function display_defaultoptions() {
      // in order to acccess "static fields",
      // you use the class id, followed by double colon,
      // not "$this->*"
      print_r(Foo::$defaults);
    }
} // class Foo

class Bar extends Foo {
private 
    // (1) "private" only accessed by the class itself,
    // neither external code, or subclasses,
    // (2) "static", specific to the class,
    static $defaults = array(1, 2);

    // when using "static fields" in constructor,
    // you need to override constructor
    public function __construct($options){
        array_push($this->options, Bar::$defaults);
    }

    public function display_defaultoptions() {
      // in order to acccess "static fields",
      // you use the class id, followed by double colon
      // not "$this->*"
      print_r(Bar::$defaults);
    }
} // class Bar

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->print();
```

Cheers

Comment: OP is requesting a childclass ('Bar') without a constructor.

Comment: @watcher, Yes, I know. I working how to make around this, due to "static fields". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but you just intricated the @watcher solution